# Nginx limit_rate to all except local host IP's

Tags: nginx, localhost, limit

So in Nginx my location config allows MP4 streams as follows but i want to limit the rate to all traffic except those specific localhost IP's i specify.

So the IP addresses i don't want to have the transfer limit are as follows :

```
172.16.0.1
172.16.0.2
172.16.0.3
172.16.0.4
172.16.0.5
172.16.0.6
etc etc
```

Nginx Config of MP4 stream :

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
mp4;

limit_rate_after 1m;
limit_rate 1m;

root '//172.16.0.1/Storage1/server/domain/public_www';

expires max;

valid_referers none blocked domain.com *.domain.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
return   403;
}

}
```

So yeah any help with what the configuration tweak i should make or change / do to allow only my localhost IP's to recieve the mp4 file without being limited by the limit_rate config would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP block of Nginx Config

```
geo $remove_rate_limit {
default 0;
172.16.0.0/24 1;
}
```

In Server Location Block of Nginx Config

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
mp4;

limit_rate_after 1m; #All users will be limited
limit_rate 1m; #All users will be limited

#Order this after the limit_rate to remove the limit for specific IP's
if ($remove_rate_limit) { #If IP matches
limit_rate_after 0; #Make 0 what is default setting for no limit.
limit_rate 0; #Make 0 what is default setting for no limit.
}

root '//172.16.0.1/Storage1/server/domain/public_www';

expires max;

valid_referers none blocked domain.com *.domain.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
return   403;
}

}
```